# Consequences of increase Oplog to large size

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-4.2

I'm trying to add a new member (m*-server: 4.2.7) in my replica set (m*-servers: 4.2.1),
and it can't sync in time, after the initial sync it changes state to RECOVERING and have: `(~ 4.3 - 6.31 hrs) behind the primary`; Oplog size: `"usedMB" : 50769.34, "timeDiffHours" : 1.19 ( ~0.79 -1.19)`.

I can't optimize queries or reduce size of dbs (~1.9T), or make backup and copy data (there is not enough time),
so think only solution for me is `replSetResizeOplog` on all members.

Question:
What the consequences can be I if increase size of Oplog larger than Upper Bound: 50GB (WiredTiger Storage Engine) to for example: 400 Gb?

Comment: If you ever need to take a full backup, or just incremental backup of oplog, backup will take a lot of space.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing negative, if you don't count the usage of disk space.  Actually you need just make your Primary nodes OpLog bigger and then wait at least that 6 hours to fill it enough. But of course it's good to have same size OpLog on every RS node.
I try to keep OpLog size at least 48h. That gives you "time" to solve problems, if those rise up.

To change OpLog size, use [replSetResizeOplog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/replSetResizeOplog/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.replSetResizeOplog) -command. Making you OpLog bigger don't change your MongoD memory usage. MongoD will always use all available memory.

Comment: Great, work done. Thank for advice

Comment: so how to increase it? will it increase the node's memory usage? For example, I increase from 1GB to 4 GB, but my primary and replica nodes is only 4GB totally.

Comment: @Bill Check my edit to original answer.

Comment: So the oplog can be larger than memory. Second, if the db size (get the size when do the backup) is 3GB, then what's the suitable for oplog size?

Comment: Suitable OpLog size is not directly related to DB size. Even your DB size is "small" you may have lots of changes. When you have lots of changes, it's good to keep OpLog bigger, so it will cover a longer period (in time) of changes. However, if the total size of DB is small, secondaries can do initial replication so fast that bigger OpLog don't matter that much.